# Python/lxml: How do I capture a row in an HTML table?

Tags: python, html-table, html-parsing, lxml

For my stock screening tool, I must switch from BeautifulSoup to lxml in my script.  After my Python script downloaded the web pages I need to process, BeautifulSoup was able to parse them properly, but the process is too slow.  Parsing the balance sheet, income statement, and cash flow statement of just one stock takes BeautifulSoup about 10 seconds, and that is unacceptably slow given that my script has over 5000 stocks to analyze.

According to some benchmark tests (http://www.crummy.com/2012/1/22/0), lxml is nearly 100 times faster than BeautifulSoup.  Thus, lxml should be able to complete within 10 minutes a job that would take BeautifuSoup 14 hours.

How can I use HTML to capture the contents of a row in an HTML table?  An example of an HTML page that my script has downloaded and needs to parse is at http://www.smartmoney.com/quote/FAST/?story=financials&opt=YB

The source code that uses BeautifulSoup to parse this HTML table is:

```
    url_local = local_balancesheet (symbol_input)
    url_local = "file://" + url_local
    page = urllib2.urlopen (url_local)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (page)
    soup_line_item = soup.findAll(text=title_input)[0].parent.parent.parent
    list_output = soup_line_item.findAll('td') # List of elements
```

If I'm looking for cash and short term investments, title_input = "Cash & Short Term Investments".

How can I do the same function in lxml?

Comment: From additional Google searches, it looks like the way to go is to lxml, etree, HTMLparser, and xpath.  xpath has code for specifying what to look for.  How do I get xpath to look for a row in an HTML table containing certain text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lxml parser with BeautifulSoup, so I don't know why you're doing this.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
```

**edit:** Here's some code to play with.  This runs in about six seconds for me.

```
def get_page_data(url):
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
    f.close()
    trs = soup.findAll('tr')
    data = {}
    for tr in trs:
        try:
            if tr.div.text.strip() in ('Cash & Short Term Investments', 'Property, Plant & Equipment - Gross',
                               'Total Liabilities', 'Preferred Stock (Carrying Value)'):
                data[tr.div.text] = [int(''.join(e.text.strip().split(','))) for e in tr.findAll('td')]
        except (AttributeError, ValueError):
            # headers dont have a tr tag, and thus raises AttributeError
            # 'Fiscal Year Ending in 2011' raises ValueError
            pass
    return data
```

Comment: I replaced BeautifulSoup 3 with BeautifulSoup4 and used the above command to call lxml in BeautifulSoup.  Unfortunately, I don't see a signficant speed improvement.  How do I get a 100-fold (or even a 10-fold) speed improvement over what I was using before?

Comment: The parsing isn't the issue then, its your analysis and searching.  You only parse each page *once*, and parsing a page should take less than a second with lxml.  What numbers do you need to get out of that page?  Maybe I can figure out a way to do it quickly.

Comment: The figures I need to capture are on the balance sheet page are: Cash & Short Term Investments; Property, Plant & Equipment - Gross; Total Liabilities; and Preferred Stock (Carrying Value).

Comment: That code snippet I provided is part of a function that gets called multiple times.  Is this slowing my script down?  Are you suggesting that I have my script open the balance sheet page JUST ONCE and get the cash, plant/equipment, liabilities, and preferred stock figure all in one shot?

Comment: You're opening it multiple times?  Let me update the post with a piece of code that grabs all of that information in one go.

Comment: 6 seconds is still too long given that I have over 5000 stocks to analyze.

How do I get that 90-fold speed improvement that lxml offers over BeautifulSoup?